trouble with android Sdk and adb
so i wanted to create an app for android and i wanted to use react native for it, but i can't make it work.
I installed everything and followed every guides, i installed watchman, openjdk, Android Studio and exported the path for android sdk in the ~/.bashrc file.
here is the exported path:
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools 

but in the moment i try to start my app on the android emulator it doesn't work and give me this error:
npx expo start --android
Starting project at /home/mema/Scrivania/base/mancie
Starting Metro Bundler
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /root/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /root/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Here is the information of my pc:
Informazioni sull'hardware:

Modello hardware:                            Acer Nitro AN515-57
Memoria:                                     16,0 GiB
Processore:                                  11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11800H × 16
Scheda grafica:                              Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)
Scheda grafica 1:                            NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3050 Ti Laptop GPU
Capacità del disco:                          (null)

please, help me.
Informazioni sul software:

Versione del firmware:                       V1.20
Nome del sistema operativo                   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Build del sistema operativo:                 (null)
Tipo di sistema operativo:                   64-bit
Versione di GNOME:                           46
Gestore grafico:                             X11
Versione del kernel:                         Linux 6.8.0-36-generic

